# Replace string at a given position with PowerShell

Tags: string, powershell, replace

I have a folder where stand 4000 csv files right now in production with a running incident.

With PowerShell I would like to replace:

```
In all files => OK
In all lines => OK
```

All string from position start 9 to position end 18 without any consideration about current string content. I guess just a question of right regular expression to use but not able to.

```
-replace 'WhatToUse','MyNewString'
```

Example: (All files contain different strings, 08.10.2016 is not a fixed string)

```
3162498;08.10.2016;30.10.2016;CHN;
```

Would become

```
3162498;MyNewString;30.10.2016;CHN;
```

Comment: `-replace '^(\d+?);(.+?);', '$1;newstring;'`

Answer (score 12):

If you are sure about the positions you could do it like this:

```
$old = "3162498;08.10.2016;30.10.2016;CHN;"
$new = $old.remove(8,10).insert(8,"MyNewString")
```

would result in this: 3162498;MyNewString;30.10.2016;CHN;

Answer (score 0):

try this (verify if its ok)

```
    $pathwithfiles= "C:\temp" 
    $stringtosearh="toto"
    $stringtoreplace="titi"
    $delimitercsv=";"


    $listfil=gci -Path $pathwithfiles -Recurse -File -Filter "*.csv"


    foreach ($currentfile in $listfil)
    {
        $contentfile=get-content $currentfile.FullName
        [string[]]$contentfileres=@()
        $numline=0

        foreach ($row in $contentfile)
        {

        $numline++ 

            if ($numline -eq 1)
            {
                $contentfileres+=$row 
                continue
            }
            else
            {
            [string[]] $linearray=$row -split $delimitercsv
            [string[]] $linearrayres=@()


                for ($i = 0; $i -lt $linearray.Count; $i++)
                { 

                       if ($i -ge 9 -and $i -le 18)
                        {
                        $linearrayres+=$linearray[$i].Replace($stringtosearh, $stringtoreplace)
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        $linearrayres+=$linearray[$i] 
                        }
                }

                $contentfileres+=($linearrayres -join $delimitercsv)

            }

        }

        $contentfileres | out-file ($currentfile.FullName )

        Write-Host "File $currentfile.FullName replaced"
    }
```

Comment: What does this gigantic uncommented blob of code have to do with the question?

Comment: this "gigantic uncommented blob of code" replace strins to position 9 to 18 in all csv in directory gived, like asked... Have you anything better to suggest that criticism?